# How to Check if an Object is a Collection

Tags: collections, vbscript

I keep getting this error in one of my scripts:

> Object is Not a Collection

So I would like to create a function which checks whether or not the object is a collection before performing any operations on it.

So far I have created this:

```
Function IsCollection(param)
    If IsEmpty(param) Then
        IsCollection = False
    ElseIf(TypeName(param) = "String") Then
        IsCollection = False
    Else
        IsCollection = True
    End If
End Function
```

But I get the feeling I am missing some checks - surely the only available types aren't just `String`, `Empty` or `Collection`?

I thought it could be better to just try and enumerate `param` and if this returns an error, then I know to output `false` - does this seem like a better alternative?

```
Function IsCollection(param)
    For Each p In param
        ' Anything need to go here?
    Next

    If Err > 0 Then
        IsCollection = False
    Else
        IsCollection = True
    End If
End Function
```

Even in the second example, would it be wise to specify whether the error given is "Object is not a collection"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript doesn't really support type introspection. You could check the [`TypeName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y58s1cs6) of `param`, but then you'd need an authoritative list of all classes that implement an enumerable interface.

I'd say your best bet is indeed to actually try to enumerate `param` and check if you get a [runtime error 451](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe43cc8d%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
Function IsCollection(param)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each p In param
        Exit For
    Next
    If Err Then
        If Err.Number = 451 Then
            IsCollection = False
        Else
            WScript.Echo "Unexpected error (0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & "): " & _
                Err.Description
            WScript.Quit 1
        End If
    Else
        IsCollection = True
    End If
End Function
```

Make sure you leave the scope of `On Error Resume Next` as localized as possible, preferably use it just inside this function.

---

As Tomalak mentioned in the comments, the above will report not only "normal" collections as collections, but also VBScript builtin arrays (since they're enumerable as well). To avoid that change the line

```
IsCollection = True
```

to

```
IsCollection = Not IsArray(param)
```

Comment: This classifies arrays as collections. Which, technically, they are, but still it's unexpected. I would modify the last line to `IsCollection = Not IsArray(param)`.